# Problem with RF circuit using HT12D and HT12E

Tags: rf, microprocessor

I am making a circuit using my RF TX and RX on 315 Mhz, already paired, and I have done the following circuit: powering it with 5V and GND from arduino:
[image][image]
And the picture of the circuit done:
[image][image][image][image][image][image]

when I power the circuit up, the LED which would be suposed to be on default dont light up.. what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you really need to post that many images (without the full URLS, no less)?

Comment: he's new. truncated www paste works better

Comment: @Richman: I know but, (and I'm going to sound like Olin here) it should be easy to see how inconvenient it is, even for a new user.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Hah! Yah but I agree.

Comment: he's new and cant post images!

Comment: @Richman: Yeah, I got that. I never complained that he couldn't post images.

Comment: 1st check power&gnd is reaching each device with voltmeter from  missing jumper errors.

Comment: Second what are the characteristic of your LED? Because if it has a drop voltage of 1.2V it means you have 3.8V on RX0 which means you have a current of 3.8mA with a resistance of 1k. Usually LEDs are more like 10-20mA so it may not be enough to light up your LED.

Comment: @damien it works that way, all the LEDS are working, tested them already, before I had the enconder left side to GND it lighted up the leds, but now not anymore

Comment: , @Richman I'll check it, but the at the right side of the decoder is not passing voltage, otherwise the LEDS would light up =/

Comment: I have tried just now to connect the Data IN pin of the encoder to the Data OUT of the decoder, and still not working, i have exchanged the encoder and decoder, also the rf modules, i have 5 pairs of each, still not working, but now the led of the encoder has lighted up when i changed RX module, and it is always receiving data, but not from the encoder orginally

Comment: Are you sure about your Rosc resistance? it looks like you're frequency is not the same for the encoder and decoder

Comment: What are Rosc? well, it is suposed to have the same frequency in both of them, RF modules and ENCODER/DECODER, a friend of mine made it with the same resources, but he is not avaiable right now to ask help :S

Comment: Rosc is the resistance between OSC1 and OSC2 and you do not have the same for encoder and decoder

Comment: I'm suposed to have the same one? didnt knew, gonna try out that now, wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your awnser, after studying a little bit into the RF module I found out my problem, the left side of both encoder and decoder are the Address PIN, which means they will only communicate if those addresses are the same, that was what I was making wrong, I left them all at 1 and changed the resistors in them both cause the TX need to have 20 times the resistence of the receiver, in other words 50k and 1M resistors.

All is working now, thanks to all.

Comment: So, you are saying, when you grounded all the pins on the left of HT12D and 12E, it worked? I'm working on a similar circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I see you do not have jumpers to join each side of the power rails.  Note there is a gap on both sides down the middle for the Blue and Red outer rails.

Remember I said check power?  That means you need an inexpensive multimeter to do this.

Best practice of using the breadboard is to use short solid wire leads and neatly connect flush to the board without large inductive loops. Keep IC's close toegether and imagine that it is a printed circtuit board layout. Add decoupling caps close to the IC.
Avoid long jumper wires at all costs.

[image]

For fun here is a [**free tool**](http://fritzing.org/download/) to help design, layout and simulate.
http://fritzing.org

I've never tried this before but looks ok.. Use staples for power and ground rails.  Don't use wire with thick insulation. Try to get thin solid wire 24 AWG I believe. and lay down flat.
[image]